# I cannot get container and dependency injection to work with slim 3

Tags: php, web, dependency-injection, slim, slim-3

Im trying to setup dependency injection in Slim v3 but to no avail.
I keep getting
`127.0.0.1:42766 [500]: GET /composers - Uncaught Error: Class 'Composer\ComposerDataAccess' not found in /home/thor/personal-repos/composers-api/src/public/ioc.php:22`
my file structure looks like this:

[image]

My class with dependencies I try to add to the container looks like this. The logger and the db seems to work. Just not the classes i added my self.

[image]

Im trying to use the dependency in my route like this, but it doesn't work and keep throwing error at me.
[image]

Edit: I am not a smart man, file names are case sensitive to the autoloader I guess. So renaming the files to start with uppercases did it.

Comment: Hi. While these are nice screenshots it is frowned upon posting images instead of code.

Comment: Not sure what `Composer\ComposerDataAccess` is but try `\Composer\ComposerDataAccess` instead.